# Matlab/Octave Solving Matrix Using Gauss Seidel not Converging

Tags: matlab, octave

Something totally impossible is happening. I have run the following code multiple times on the **same** Matrix and always converged to a solution using the Gauss Seidel method within 10 iterations.

My Gauss Seidel function definition is:

```
function xnew = gauss_seidel(A, b, xold)
  n = size(A)(1);
  At = A;
  xnew = xold;
  for i = 1 : n
    At(n, n) = 0;
  end
  for i = 1 : n
    xnew(i) = (b(i) - At(i, :)*xnew)/A(i, i);
  end
endfunction
```

Setting up the coefficient matrix, the solution vector and the initial approximate vector:

```
A = [20 1 -1; 1 -10 1; -1 1 10];
b = [17 13 18]';
x = [0 0 0]';
```

Using the Gauss Seidel method:

```
>> x = gauss_seidel(A, b, x)
Test
x =

   0.85000
  -1.21500
   2.00650

>> x = gauss_seidel(A, b, x)
Test
x =

   0.16107
   0.13176
   1.80293

>> x = gauss_seidel(A, b, x)
Test
x =

   0.77248
  -1.17422
   1.99467

>> x = gauss_seidel(A, b, x)
Test
x =

   0.235961
   0.097279
   1.813868
```

etc... etc... Can someone please guide me into what error I am possibly making that is not allowing my code to converge?

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse, the impossible isn't possible. A freak accident left me typing the wrong characters. A piece of the code below should equal **(i, i)**

```
function xnew = gauss_seidel(A, b, xold)
  n = size(A)(1);
  At = A;
  xnew = xold;
  for i = 1 : n
    At(n, n) = 0; //THIS SHOULD EQUAL (i, i)
  end
  for i = 1 : n
    xnew(i) = (b(i) - At(i, :)*xnew)/A(i, i);
  end
endfunction
```